# Change route parameter in Angular

Tags: angular, router, angular-routing

I had for example an URL like this

```
/mycomponent(sidebar:detail/:id)
```

now I want to change my Url if the :id is not given and set another value for the param.
The problem is, the `params` property on the `ActivatedRoute` is read only.

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically do a redirect if it is not set.

Better than that just create a variable in your controller. It reads the ID but if the ID is not set then set the variable to your default value. Then everything in your component reads from this var and not directly from the param value.

Pseudocode:

```
const myParamId = param.id || 5
```

Comment: Thats not my problem, the goal that there are the Url changed to had the possibility for a bookmark and I try to implement it generally so I only had the ActivatedRoute for informations

Answer (score 0):

You can just forcefully navigate away to your desired route. You can use either `navigate` or `navigateByUrl`.

```
this.route.params
    .subscribe(params=>{
        if(params.id === null || params.id ===undefined){
            this.route.navigate(['sidebar/detail/defaultId'])
        }
    })
```

But I do think that you should try redirects (maybe look into [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)?) instead of navigate away inside a component. A well defined route (with proper redirects and fallbacks) is much much cleaner.